# How do i add aliasing to text?

Tags: html, css

So i'm making a 90's styled website and i'd like to add aliasing to text to make it look less better quality, but i can't find anything on the internet to make that. can someone help ?

Comment: I suggest that you lookup a font which has these characteristics. As far as I know there is no way to "degrade" the quality of text. Maybe look for an example that has the style you want and try to figure out how the site implemented it.

Answer (score 1):

Using custom fonts is definitely a good place to start.
Rather than trying to lower the quality of your render, you can just import a webfont that looks more like the style you're looking for and implement it in your css.
It's pretty simple to do and if you choose your weights and styles correctly, it shouldn't consume much bandwidth.

Check https://fonts.google.com/
They have a plethora of free webfonts that you can import simply by using the @import rule at the top of your stylesheet.
e.g.:
`@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lexend+Deca&display=swap');`

And then you can just use it normally after that:

```
.myParagraphClass{
font-family: "Lexend Deca";
}
```